# JNI : Get java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, c++, c, eclipse, java-native-interface

This has been asked several time and have different accepted answers. but none of them worked for me.
I have made a jni dll from my project to use in 64x windows 7 working with eclipse and jdk1.7.0_10 (64bit). but after loading my DLL i get  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError.
I started to create a helloworld project based on this [guide](http://electrofriends.com/articles/jni/jni-part1-java-native-interface/). and i do everything it said. but i already get this error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: test.HelloWorld.print()V
    at test.HelloWorld.print(Native Method)
    at test.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:24)
```

**Yes I have included the library path** and **yes i have build the C project for x64** and **yes i'm using 64bit jvm.**

Codes:

```
package test;

public class HelloWorld {
    public native void print();  //native method
    static   //static initializer code
    {
        try{
            System.loadLibrary("CLibHelloWorld");

               }
               catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
                  System.err.println("Native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
                  System.exit(1);
                }

    } 

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        HelloWorld hw = new HelloWorld();
        hw.print();             //   ==>  i get error on this line
    }
}
```

and

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class HelloWorld */

#ifndef _Included_HelloWorld
#define _Included_HelloWorld
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     HelloWorld
 * Method:    print
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_print
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

and

```
#include "HelloWorld.h"
#include "jni.h"
#include  "stdio.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_print(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
  printf("Hello world\n");
  return;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, and because it might help you debug your problem, if you try with [JavaCPP](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp), does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C name for `test.HelloWorld.print` is

```
Java_test_HelloWorld_print
```

you are missing the `_test` - did you run javah with the class in the default package?

Comment: in my project i have functions like: **Java_Secure_Key_connect**
 so in java i have created project named **test**  then a package named **Secure** with a class named **key** and call native **connect** function in that class. should this work or i have made mistake?

Comment: I think names are case sensitive so the class needs to be `Key` otherwise I think that is OK.

Answer (score 0):

You have miss the package name **test**
you should include your package name in c